# ListItem/FlatList is not rendering data from GraphQL API

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql

This is very interesting. I am not getting any errors but my data from GraphQL API is not being rendered into a FlatList. All that I am seeing in my UsersScreen is the Text component. I was getting errors before because my data was an object instead of an array but even after passing my object as an array, FlatList is not recognizing the data

```
import { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify'
import { Text, View, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';



const listUsers = `query listUsers {
  listUsers {
      username


  }
}`;



export default function UsersScreen() {

const [allUsers, setAllUsers] = useState([]);

  listQuery = async () => {
    const allUsers = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listUsers));
    setAllUsers(allUsers);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(listUsers, null, 2));


  };

  keyExtractor = (_item, index) => index.toString()
  renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <ListItem
      title={item.username}
    />
  )

  return(
    <View> 
      <Text>All Users</Text>
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
        data={allUsers}
        renderItem={renderItem}
      /> 
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: what is your alluser data?

Comment: allUsers is the state variable and setAllUsers is the method. ListUsers is the name of the data.

Answer (score 0):

in your code, I do not find the `listQuery` method called. you can use the React.useEffect, which has the same effect as `componentDidMount`,`componentDidUpdate`,
`componentWillUnmount`.you can try the following code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

....

useEffect(() => {
    listQuery();
  },[allUsers]);
```

Comment: I tried this but I am getting the error message "that allUsers is not defined"

Comment: API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listUsers)) this returns what? could you paste it

Comment: console.log returns "query listUsers {\n  listUsers {\n      username\n  }\n}"

Comment: The Query works fine in GraphQL and when using a button component, I am able to see the data I want which is usernames. "<Button onPress={this.listQuery} title={GraphQL}/>" The problem is when trying to return a Flatlist, I get an error message  of undefined or no data is returned and have a blank screen.

Comment: the query does not return any value. `query listUsers {\n listUsers {\n username\n }\n}"`, the usename not has value. so you get error info. it should return this format result:`{[{username:"someUser"},{username:"oneuser"}]}`

Comment: ok I made a small change to my code. Right now my console.log returns this {
  "data": {
    "listUsers": [
      {
        "username": "TestUser"
      },
      {
        "username": "String"
      },
      {
        "username": "johnnysmith"
      },
      {
        "username": "String"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: But I am still not seeing that data rendered as a FlatList

Comment: try to change `setAllUsers(allUsers);` to `setAllUsers(allUsers.data)`

Comment: I made changes to the code where I set allUsers to an array. "const allUsers = [ ]", the code for ListQuery and Useeffect is still the same. Console.log works but the problem now is FlatList/ListItem is not recognizing my data

Comment: you can try to use static data to debug your FlatList/ListItems.if it shows, it is your data format is wrong. `const allUsers = [
  { username: 'First Item'},{username: 'Second Item'},{ username: 'Third Item'},];`

Comment: Yea FlatList/ListItem work when using static data so it could be the data format

Comment: @tobiappdeveloper; if it helps you, please upvote it or accept it. thanks

Comment: I am still trying to find a solution but thanks so much for your help